# jQuery UI smooth transitions using CSS where possible

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, transition

Is there a plugin / procedure / CSS line / different method to integrate with the jQuery UI framework so that it can take advantage of hardware accelerated transitions where possible.

For example one site is using a gallery that users the UI framework to slide images in and out on user clicks of corresponding arrows. I'd like this to be as smooth as possible.

Comment: You can't directly access hardware acceleration with javascript, but most browsers (other than IE9 and below) can use css transitions, which should be fairly quick and smooth. For cross-browser, my suggestion for keeping it smooth would be to keep images small and optimize code where possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access/add hardware accelerated css transforms using jQuery. However jQueryUI doesn't use css transforms for its stock animations.

This means that you would have to manually create a slide animation in css. An example,

```
 $("#myDiv").css("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(800px, 0px, 0px)"); 
 //or some other transform type, (this is specifically for webkit)
```

Then in your css, you'd need an easing function like:

```
#mydiv {
   -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
   transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
}
```

This will give you a hardware accelerated transition that moves #myDiv 800px to the right.

Answer (score 1):

I found [a very useful jquery plugin called jquery-animate-enhanced](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/) that uses css transitions for animations where posssible.  I was having trouble with sliding transitions being very choppy in mobile webkit browsers and this worked wonders.

http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/

Comment: Unless it has been updated the plugin is usueally more trouble than its worth. It rationalises positions and multiplications diferent than jQuery's standard animate function so you find that with more complicated animations your elements end up positioned perfectly either with CSS3 transitions or javascript animate ... NOT BOTH.

Comment: It has been updated, but I'm not sure if it solved whatever problems you were experiencing. For me it definitely solved my issues in a quick, trouble-free way without me having to learn the internals of css3 transitions, which is what i was after. I am, however, just using simple bidirectional slide-in, slide-out animations.